# Log4j2: Logging file level affecting console level

Tags: logging, log4j2

Why `logger.file.level` affecting `rootLogger.level` in this settings (**log4j2.properties**)?

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1}: %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName = logs/TEMOS.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1}: %msg%n

loggers = file

logger.file.name=org.company.test
logger.file.level = info
logger.file.append = false
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = all
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

The console contains only *info messages* as well as file. After change `logger.file.level` to *all*, console contains *all messages* as well as file.

Comment: You may have found a bug. Please raise a ticket on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker.

Comment: Ticket raised: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1702. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. It was implemented this way to match the behavior of its predecessors, Log4j 1 and Logback. The Level attribute specified on the Logger is ONLY checked for the first LoggerConfig. If it passes that then it will be passed to all parent LoggerConfigs until it is rejected either by a Filter or by having additivity="false" specified on the parent.